# Sending mail using sendmail

Tags: sendmail

Need a few clarifications regarding sending mail using `sendmail`.

I actually configured [Bugzilla](http://www.bugzilla.org/about/) on a test server. The configuration was successful and I am now able to use it.

I also want that, whenever a new bug is created or any bug is updated, a mail to be sent. For that, I already installed sendmail on my system and started the service, but mails are not being sent.

Following can be seen in my maillog file:

```
Apr 18 21:56:50 serverlinux sendmail[3827]: r3IGQhF1003825: 
    to=<xxxxx@ymail.com>,
    ctladdr=<zaman@serverlinux.example.com> (500/500),
    delay=00:00:07,
    xdelay=00:00:06,
    mailer=esmtp,
    pri=120372,
    relay=mta6.am0.yahoodns.net. [66.196.118.240],
    dsn=5.0.0,
    stat=Service unavailable
```

I am not sure whether just starting the sendmail service will help me to send mails or if I need to configure some parameter in sendmail.

How can I send mails using sendmail to any valid email-ids in the Internet domain?

Comment: Does your ISP filter port 25?

Comment: Could you post **all** r3IGQhF1003825 log entries? [`from=` and `to=`]

Comment: I am using the following command to send mail